# Ubuntu 18.04 shutdown and other power/charging problems

Tags: kernel, power-management, shutdown, battery, charging

Quite new to Ubuntu/Linux and just installed 18.04 (Bionic) onto my Windows 10 Netbook. 32-bit EFI/BIOS and 64-bit System, used a workaround, but installation wasn't a problem.

The Netbook will not shutdown. It stops forever at kvm: exiting hardware virtualization, sometimes after a longer period it might go to black screen, but doesn't power off. All the terminal commands to shutdown or power off or force shutdown, do not change anything. Still have to push the power button for several seconds to really turn off power.
The exxception is

```
sudo poweroff -f
```

This does nothing besides causing Terminal to print power-off and freeze at a blinking cursor.

There are other charging problems that likely have the same source. The internal battery charges until a certain point during boot-up, stops charging and doesn't continue (external control LED). I have to physically remove the clinch and plug it back in, then it starts charging again. If the internal battery reaches 100% the same thing happens, charging shuts off and the battery will lose charge, but charging will not start again until I take out the clinch and plug it back in again. The computer is a Medion 1240

Devices:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 36)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 36)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 91)
```

upower:

```
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_axp288_charger
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_axp288_fuel_gauge
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

I don't know a lot of terminal commands, so if additional information is needed, please ask.

Comment: this is a nomodeset needed in grub issue.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean exactly. Thanks in advance. in grub_cmdline_linux_default I included nomodeset if thats what you meant. Didn't change anything, unfortunately, even after re-boot.

Comment: that's what I meant. unfortunately I was wrong. is `acpi=force` any better?

Comment: I have also tried that inside and outside of the quotation marks, didn't change the power-off problem, however there were some differences in the lines I saw during shutdown.